# Implementing a USB hub with MITM (packet interception) capabilities

Tags: integrated-circuit, usb-device, linux, usb-host, usb-hub

I'm working on a project in which I essentially need to implement a USB hub that also contains an embedded Linux SoC that would man-in-the-middle the connection between an upstream USB host and a single downstream USB device, allowing me to ingest the traffic from the host with a Linux application and ultimately modify or eat the traffic.

My question is: do there exist USB hub ICs that permit this sort of functionality (i.e. a USB hub IC that exposes its traffic)? I've spent a while searching and not found anything. I believe the closest I've found so far is something like the [Microchip USB7206](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/USB7206#document-table) or [Maxim MAX3420E](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3420E.pdf), which have some extra features but seem to still be far from what I'm looking for. I have a feeling this is impossible from a USB protocol perspective and such a chip does not exist. That said, before starting on my fallback plan, I'd like to make sure I'm not just missing search terms and vocabulary.

The fallback plan would be finding or designing a board that can mimic a USB hub using two USB controllers (one host and one device) both peripheral to a Linux SoC, and then manually intercepting and filtering or passing through USB packets by reading from one USB port and writing to the other. I wanted to avoid this solution because ideally my intercepting device would be invisible, acting like a true USB hub, rather than spoofing or having to recreate the device descriptors, etc. of the downstream device for the benefit of the upstream. I'd be willing to do it but it seemed like a big undertaking in comparison to integrating an IC that already provides hub capabilities.

Comment: What USB speeds do you need to support?  There are off-the-shelf protocol analyzers that can monitor USB traffic, WIreShark can log USB traffic on the host.  If you actually need to do logging/intercept in a custom hub, you are probably going to have to use USB transceivers connected to a FPGA.  Which transceivers will depend on what USB standards you need to support.

Comment: @DeanFranks Not certain but it looks like most of the devices will be using USB 2 or will be backwards compatible. There definitely won't be anything with high throughput, just printers and other such peripherals. What makes you say an FPGA would be necessary? Because of the latency requirements of doing this sort of "deep packet inspection" (for lack of a better term) without messing up USB timing?

Comment: Because I seriously doubt there will be any off the shelf silicon that does what you want.  USB hubs are pretty cost sensitive items and adding the fast processor or the high speed ports required to intercept and/or filter usb traffic would be a significant expense in both silicon and power that would be unlikely to appeal to any high volume customers.

Comment: @DeanFranks Okay, interesting, hadn't considered this. What about the fallback? Assuming I already needed Linux for other reasons (e.g. some libraries that are going to help me parse traffic; uploading some intercepted data to a cloud storage bucket), would this be a viable alternative to using an FPGA?

Comment: I don't think that linux is going to help you if you need to sit in the middle (implementing a transparent tunnel between a host port and an OTG port in device mode would be non-trivial).  If you want a solution, state the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @DeanFranks There's not much more to it than that. I'll be parsing and modifying the input to a thermal printer, for which there exist libraries in some high-level languages. I'll also need to authenticate with a web service, upload the intercepted traffic, provide connectivity for setup/administration, etc., so I really do need that operating system.

Comment: That describes your solution, not the problem you are trying to solve.  I suspect that USB intercept/parse/modify is going to prove to be non-viable unless you have extensive experience with FPGA development, low level USB details and deep pockets.